# Algebra of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that a polynomial is something completely different from a polynomial function , but under one condition there is an isomorphism between the algebra of polynomials and algebra of polynomial functions.The condition is the infinity of the field which the algebras are defined over. I really wonder why this condition is necessary and sufficient . I mean what does this condition do ? what is it's role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morphism $f:K[X]\to K^K$ from polynomials to functions on$~K$, over a *field* $K$, is indeed injective if and only if $K$ is finite, and its image is by definition the algebra of polynomial functions. To see the role of finiteness more clearly, it is useful to generalise by replacing $K$ throughout by a commutative ring$~R$, for which the morphism$~f$ is still defined (which would not be the case if $R$ were non commutative).

One direction is obvious: $R[X]$ is an infinite set for *any* non-trivial ring $R$ (the monomials $X^n$ are all distinct) but the set $R^R$ of $R$-values functions on $R$ is finite whenever $R$ is finite, so $f$ cannot possibly be injective in this case for cardinality reasons. So for every finite commutative ring, the algebra of polynomials is *not isomorphic* to the algebra of polynomial functions (with the sole exception of the [trivial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_ring), where both algebras are also instances of the trivial ring).

In the other direction the key property is the bound $\deg(P)$ of the number of roots of a nonzero polynomial $P$, which holds whenever $R$ is an *integral domain*. This prevents such $P$ from appearing in the kernel of the morphism when $R$ is infinite, as $P$ would need to have all elements of$~R$ as roots. It is therefore true that whenever $R$ is an infinite integral domain, then distinct polynomials have distinct polynomial functions, and the algebra of polynomial functions is isomorphic to $R[X]$. That this is no longer true without the hypothesis of integral domain is shown by any infinite [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) $R$, where the nonzero polynomial $X^2-X$ has an associated polynomial function that is zero on $R$.

While for a finite fields$~K$ the morphism $f$ is not injective, it *is* surjective: every function $K\to K$ is a polynomial function (and uniquely so if the degree of the polynomial is required to be less than$~|K|$). This is easy to show by using [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation#Definition) to get the desired function values on the set of all points of$~K$. This result trivially extends to finite integral domains (which are in fact just fields) and easily to products of finite fields (in particular to $R=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ when $n$ is *square free*) but it fails whenever the characteristic of$~R$ is divisible by the square $p^2$ of some prime number, since polynomial functions are automatically compatible with reduction modulo$~p$, but in this case not all functions are, notably not the characteristic function of a single element. Finally note that, apart from the case of the trivial ring, $R[X]$ is *never isomorphic* to the algebra of all functions, for cardinality reasons.

Comment: In your last paragraph you said every function is a polynomial and it is easy to show by Lagrange interpolation .How?

Comment: I've added a slightly more detailed description of what to do for Lagrange interpolation, whose basic formula works over any field. The essence here is that you can get the characteristic function for a point $a\in K$ by taking $\prod_{c\in K\setminus\{a\}}(X-c)$, whose polynomial function is nonzero at$~a$ and vanishes on all other points of$~K$; its value$~v$ at$~a$ might still differ from$~1$, so multiply the polynomial by $v^{-1}$ to correct that (this is where you need a field). Once you have the characteristic function, the rest is a matter of making linear combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote the *functions* with capital letters, say $\;F\;$, and the polynomials with lower case ones, say $\;f\;$ , for example the polynomial $\;f(x)=x\;$  and the polynomial (identity) function $\;F(x)=x\;$, and corresponding algebras as $\;\frak F\;,\;\frak f\;$ , resp. Define

$$\phi:\mathfrak f\to\mathfrak {F}\;:\;\;\phi(f):=F$$

Everything works fine (show this), but there's a point about injectivity:

$$F(x)=G(x)\iff (F-G)(x)=0$$

No matter what the degrees of $\;F,G\;$ are, the above rightmost equation means the *polynomial* (function) $\;F-G\;$ vanishes in infinite points (as the field is infinite by assumption), and as we know this means the corresponding polynomial (not as function!) is the zero one, from where $\;f-g=0\iff f=g\;$ and we get injectivity.

Answer (score 1):

I repeat my answer from MO:

Polynomials always are defined by its coefficients in contrary with  polynomial functions: e.g., $x^2=x$ for functions in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be an integral domain and consider  $\phi\colon R[X]\to R^R$, $f\mapsto (x\mapsto f(x))$. This is an $R$-algebra homomorphism and the image of $\phi$  is precisely the algebra of polynomial functions.
So we wonder when $\phi$ is injective.

If $R=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ is finite, then $f(X)=(X-a_1)\cdot\ldots(X-a_n)$ maps to the zero function and hence $\phi$ is not injective.
On the other hand if $\phi(f)$ is zero and $f\ne 0$, then for each $a\in R$ we find that $X-a$ divides $f$ (this is where the property "domain" is needed), but there cannot be more than $\deg f$ factors of this kind (as $f\ne 0)$

Comment: It is not true that "$a$ is root of $f$ implies $X-a$ divides $f$" depends on the property "domain": it holds for every ring (commutative or not(!), though in the non-commutative case one must prefix both "root" and "divides" by for instance "left-"), as Euclidean division by $X-a$ shows. However, one uses "integral domain" (both the commutative and the no-zero-divisors part) to get "$b$ is a root of $f=(X-a)Q$ implies that $b=a$ or $b$ is a root of $Q$".

Answer (score 1):

We can also look (regarding necessity) to an example for finite fields, say $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q \gt 1$ is a power of a prime, in which two different polynomials give rise *under the evaluation homomorphism* to the same (polynomial) function.

Indeed the canonical example is that $x^q$ and $x$ are distinct polynomials, but their values for any $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$ agree.

The fact that $x^q = x$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a consequence of the [multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ being cyclic of order $q-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36585/3111).